# FluentData.IDbCommand does not contain definition for 'Query' error

Tags: c#, orm, fluentdata

I'm new to using FluentData and working with an existing application that is using it.

When I'm trying to build in Visual Studio I first downloaded the dll and added it as a reference.

Now I get the following error:

> 'FluentData.IDbCommand' does not contain a definition for 'Query' and
>   no extension method 'Query' accepting a first argument of type
>   'FluentData.IDbCommand' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

The line of code is as follows:

```
var result = Proxy.Context.Sql(query.ToString()).Query<T>().FirstOrDefault();
```

I've also tried to delete the reference. Then open NuGet and searched for fluentdata and clicked the install button and I still get the same error. When installed if from NuGet it added the following line of code to the .config file:

```
  <package id="FluentData" version="3.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is the current version of FluentData has no such method Query in FluentData IDbCommand.

The source code on Codeplex here: http://fluentdata.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Main/FluentData/Command/Interfaces/IDbCommand.cs

The solution was to change the code to use the new methods or use the old dll. Another solution would be to remove all fluentdata from project.

Hope that helps.